# how to create google maps dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a site using Google Maps.  I am placing a large number of icons of different types on the map. As a result, I'd like to be able to filter which are shown.  To do this, I want a dropdown with checkboxes.  This is very similar to an example at [demo dropdown](http://vislab-ccom.unh.edu/~briana/examples/gdropdown/).  I tried using this as an example, but there are many functions not documented (I assume that they are in some of the other files that are not accessible.  When I save the source and open it, the dropdowns are not working.).

I just need to take a simple list and create a dropdown that is embedded on the map.  I have a sample that uses the following method of creating a set of checkboxes.  The boxes are made with:

```
var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
for (var key in names) {
    var type = names[key];
    var name = type.name;
    var id = type.id;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="' + id + '" id="' + id + '" checked="checked" />' + name;
    legend.appendChild(div);
}
```

and the html is the following:

```
<body >
      <div id="map_canvas" > </div>
         <div id="legend" ></div>
</body>
```

I just want a simple methodology.  There will only be a small number of choices, though this really makes no difference.

here is the style code

```
   <style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #legend {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 10%;
  }
  #legend h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
}
  #legend img {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
 .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
 .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
 .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}

</style>
```

here's the html

```
<div class="dropdown">
```

Dropdown
  
    Account 
    Opportunity 
    Lead

Comment: Use `click` Javascript functions to control the `display` property of the elements. You should add a `class` for the elements you wish to hide/show on click. See http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp for help regarding dropdowns.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: related question: [Google Maps API - show marker from select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574350/google-maps-api-show-marker-from-select)

Comment: Zacharel, the link you provided is very helpful. This will create the dropdown and code to operate it.  How do I embed this onto the Google Map?  will something like "map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM].push(legend);" work?

Comment: Mike Williams' Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial has a page on it [Lots of sidebar entries](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic15.htm) which has an example of how to use a dropdown (although it does depend on some of his other pages for context).  [his example ported to v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map15c.html)

Comment: Geocodezip - these are not helpful, as the issue is that I don't want sidebars, but have the dropdown in the Google map not on the side.  I'll post some code later as the one I got on W3schools above doesn't seem to work, a monstrous surprise as I assumed it would at least work.  The dropdown shows (outside the map area but different issue) but the dropdown itself does not operate.  In looking into this, I see a great deal of customizations of the CSS to get the actions.  Right now, I get NOTHING at all.

Comment: I think the issue is that I have a Google Map below the dropdown and the dropdown itself is blocking the viewing of the options.  It seems I need to get the dropdown incorporated into the map so it can be seen.  I tried several methods, but so far - nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Example over here works for me, [Customized dropdown inside googlemap](http://vislab-ccom.unh.edu/~briana/examples/gdropdown/)

You just need to check the source code, get the js and css code from these files, **gdropdown.css gdropdown.js**, located at the top. Everything will be just fine.